# Detect an object and take photo

Tags: ios, opencv, photo, core-image

You might have seen that option in one of the samsung phone that when a person smile it take the photo. So it somehow detects the smile and the click the photo automatically.
I'm trying to create the similar thing on `iOS` that lets say if the camera detects a chair it clicks the photo.
I've searched around and what I found is that there is a library called `OpenCV` but I'm not sure it'll work with `iOS` or not. Plus there is a concept of `CoreImage` in `iOS` which has something to do with deep understanding of the image.
 So any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> openCV For iOS

For detection you can use openCV framework in iOS and the native detection methods. In my application i am using openCV rectangle detection and the scenario is: after taken picture openCV detects rectangle on the image and then makes lines on detected shape, also it can crop the image with basic functionality and as perspective correction.

```
options: Face Detection, Shape Detection
```

> Native way:

iOS provides us real time detection there are many tutorials how to use them i will link at the end of the thread. Native way also provides us face detection, shape detection and perspective correction.

> Coclusion:

Choice is up to you but i prefer native way. remember openCV is written in C++ if you are using swift language you can import openCV in your project and then connect swift to objective-C to call openCV. Using `Bridging Headers`

> Tutorials:

[Medium Link 1](https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1)

[Medium Link 2](https://medium.com/pharos-production/using-opencv-in-a-swift-project-679868e1b798)

[Toptal Tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/opencv/object-detection-opencv-swift)

[How to use OPENCV in iOS](https://www.timpoulsen.com/2019/using-opencv-in-an-ios-app.html)

Comment: Voting it down ;) because the links you've given are redirected to spam sites.

Comment: i have updated Links - 4 years passed after this post, thanks for down vote <3

Comment: Hehe cool ya, don't worry. Your answer is helpful. Keep up the good work. Sorry voting it down - (removed the down vote).